# Параллельная передача POST запроса и адресация на другую страницу

Tags: php, html, smarty, платежи

На странице имеется форма с данными:

```
<form name="SendOrder" method="post" action="https://testpay.kkb.kz/jsp/process/logon.jsp">
   <input type="hidden" name="Signed_Order_B64" size="100" value="{$bookingpay}">
   <input type="hidden" name="email"  value="{$val.email}">
   <input type="hidden" name="Language" value="rus">
   <input type="hidden" name="BackLink" value="http://suite/?page=payed">
   <input type="hidden" name="PostLink" value="http://suite/?page=success">
```

После нажатия форма отправляется на оплату https://testpay.kkb.kz/jsp/process/logon.jsp в форме передается xml с моей стороны
После прохождения проверки и оплаты, банк на url PostLink отправляет xml "response". А пользователь возвращается по BackLink на сайт.
На странице маршрутизации описано так:

```
case 'success':
        $response = successpay($_POST["response"]); 
        $smarty->display('booking.tpl');
    break;
    case 'payed':
        $smarty->display('successpay.tpl');
        break;
    case 'failpay':
        $smarty->display('failure.tpl');
        break;
```

successpay находится в файле функций common.php
Вопросы: 1. Будет ли происходить обработка $_POST["response"]? Т.к. пользователь обращается не к странице page=success, а к page=payed

Comment: попробуйте изложит свой вопрос более внятно. страницы сами никуда не ходят, а при каких то действиях выполняются какие-то запросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется, "посмотреть параллельный POST запрос" нельзя. посмотреть в данном случае можно и нужно в базу данных.

Скрипт, который обрабатывает ПОСТ запрос из банка не должен ничего никому выводить, и назначать переменные для смарти в нем бессмысленно. Все что он должен сделать - это записать в БД информацию, принятую из банка, об успешности или неуспешности платежа.

А скрипт по бэклинку уже должен смотреть в БД и искать там эту информацию.

Comment: смарти часть нужна, чтобы не обращаться на прямую к common.php, разве данная реализация case 'success':
        $response = successpay($_POST["response"]); не имеет смысла?

Comment: Ты прочитал весь ответ или только строчку про смарти? ЧТО ты собрался показывать роботу банка, который обращается к твоему сайту? Он не оценит какой у тебя красивый логотип

Comment: Спасибо за логотип, который не видели) По существу:  $smarty->assign(successpay($_POST["response"])); после попадает в функцию function successpay($response)

Comment: ну так и пиши просто successpay($response) без смарти. в любом случае это не главное

Answer (score 0):

Инструменты разработчика открой. Там есть вкладка специальная. Для chrome -

[image: вот]

Отображает к каким страницам были запросы, сколько по времени они заняли и многое другое.

Comment: Данная форма постится на сервер банка, после оплаты они отправляют по url Postlink xml, а по BackLink пользователя возвращает на сайт.

Comment: @Den я до сих пор не понимаю, что вы от нас хотите. Думаю, остальные тоже не понимают. Вы можете собраться и полноценно, всесторонне, внятно, грамотно, последовательно и логично всё изложиить от начала до конца, отредактировав ваш вопрос?

Comment: Исправлено. Ипатьев понял, что я имел ввиду.